# strange set bug in python with big text file

Tags: python, text, readfile

I'm importing a very big list of names with each line having a name, and i'm adding it to a set, as follows:

```
 g = open('names.txt', 'r')
 for line in g:
    self.nameset.add(line)
```

However, I can't seem to run the most basic command on it, the if "name" in self.nameset. As in, it can't seem to ever find any name even though I know for sure the name i'm checking is in there. If I make the text file very small, however, it works fine. Am I doing something incorrectly by passing in a very large text file this way?

Thank you very much!

Comment: -1 The only way it would have worked with a "very small" file would be a one-line file with no line-separator. "i know for sure the name i'm checking is in there"?? Consider doing some debugging before asking questions -- what would `print self.nameset` have told you?

Answer (score 2):

line contains "\n", so before you add it to the set, maybe:

```
self.nameset.add(line.strip())
```